# Can't figure out the error in the mysql query

Tags: sql, mysql

I am trying for an hour now but I am still not able to figure out what's the problem in this query. :/

```
SELECT * FROM question ORDER BY question_id DESC LIMIT 3 WHERE topic_name = (SELECT * FROM topic WHERE subject_name = 'Maths')
```

This is the error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'WHERE topic_name = (SELECT * FROM topic WHERE subject_name =
>   'Maths')' at line 1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your statements are all out of order.  The correct statement is:

```
SELECT *
FROM question
WHERE topic_name = (SELECT * FROM topic WHERE subject_name = 'Maths')
ORDER BY question_id DESC LIMIT 3 ;
```

However, that won't work because of the subquery.  Perhaps you mean something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM question
WHERE topic_name in (SELECT topic_name FROM topic WHERE subject_name = 'Maths')
ORDER BY question_id DESC LIMIT 3 ;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your WHERE clause needs to go before your ORDER BY clause:

```
SELECT * FROM question WHERE topic_name IN (SELECT topic_name FROM topic WHERE subject_name = 'Maths') ORDER BY question_id DESC LIMIT 3
```

Comment: May I suggest a `MIN`, `MAX`, or `TOP 1` in the subquery, if you want to keep the `=`

Comment: I changed the `=` to `IN()` address this issue

Answer (score 0):

Specify which column and Limit the result to one or use the IN operator instead

```
SELECT * FROM question 
WHERE topic_name = (SELECT topic FROM topic WHERE subject_name = 'Maths')
ORDER BY question_id DESC LIMIT 1 

SELECT * FROM question 
WHERE topic_name in(SELECT topic FROM topic WHERE subject_name = 'Maths')
ORDER BY question_id DESC LIMIT 3
```

Actually this is not optimal advice. Do a inner join instead:

```
SELECT * FROM question q
INNER JOIN topic t 
ON q.topic_name = t.topic
WHERE subject_name = 'Maths'
ORDER BY question_id LIMIT 3
```